# Can i access more than 1 scope when requesting for token?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, scopes

I am creating API, which has multiple access levels and I have 16 routes groups (for example `users`, `users-basic`, `payments`, etc.) and each of them has a separate scope.

Question is - can I pass multiple scopes in authorize request? I want to manage permissions for every client oauth2 individually, that's why I am making APP scopes.

I have tried passing multiple scopes with commas, an array, etc. Nothing worked.

```
response: [
   error: invalid_scope,
   message: The requested scope is invalid, unknown, or malformed
   hint: Check the `users,payments` scope
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out that you can pass scopes with spaces.. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#token-scopes Assigning Scopes To Tokens